# Simple recursive function - OCAML

Tags: recursion, ocaml

Can someone take a look at what is wrong with my code? It keeps telling me that it will cause stack overflow.

```
let rec to_ten x =
  if x = 10 then x 
  else if x < 10 then to_ten x + 1 
  else to_ten x - 1
  ;;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you need to add parentheses around addition and subtraction:

```
let rec to_ten x =
  if x = 10 then x 
  else if x < 10 then to_ten (x + 1)
  else to_ten (x - 1)
```

Otherwise, operator precedence makes `to_ten x + 1` read as `((to_ten x) + 1)`, which results in an infinite loop. See [7.7.1  Precedence and associativity](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/expr.html#sec133)